# Could You Use Common cathode RGB LED without providing power to G and B

Tags: led, power, grounding, rgb

I know this kind of defeats the purpose of an (common cathode) RGB LED, but if you only wanted Red on a RGB LED would it be acceptable to use only the R pin and the Cathode pin to get just red?
Sorry in advance for my bad grammar.

Comment: yes. [15 chars]

Comment: Sure. What do you think happens when an RGB LED is displaying red only?

Comment: Certainly although is Green is brighter for you with Red-Blue low color sensitivity?  ( aka blindness)  I was diagnosed that way after successfully decoding resistor values for 30 yrs. They used pastel patterns in bad FL lighting for the nurse's test at work.

Comment: Sure.  A reason to do that might be you are in small volume production and you have 12 LEDs and all but one are multicolor.  Rather than source, drive, and stock a different part and have assembly errors due to confusion, make em all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

Your RGB LED package electrically looks like this:

[image]

It contains three LEDs that have their cathodes wired together, so presents a total of 4 pins.  Not running current thru any LED isn't going to affect the others.

Note that the point of a RGB LED package is usually to allow arbitrary colors to be displayed.  If you had to run all the LEDs at the same current, you wouldn't really have any overall color choice.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I'm really mystified what you think is wrong, misleading, or badly written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You do not have to power the other two in any way. Just leave their anode pins unconnected.